# Does ruby have real multithreading?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency

I know about the "cooperative" threading of ruby using [green threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads). How can I create real "OS-level" threads in my application in order to make use of multiple cpu cores for processing?

Answer (score 620, accepted):

**Updated with Jörg's Sept 2011 comment**

You seem to be confusing two *very* different things here: the
Ruby Programming Language and the specific threading model of one
specific implementation of the Ruby Programming Language. There
are currently around 11 different implementations of the Ruby
Programming Language, with *very* different and unique threading
models.

(Unfortunately, only two of those 11 implementations are actually
ready for production use, but by the end of the year that number
will probably go up to four or five.) (**Update**: it's now 5: MRI, JRuby, YARV (the interpreter for Ruby 1.9), Rubinius and IronRuby).

1. The first implementation doesn't actually have a name, which
   makes it quite awkward to refer to it and is really annoying and
   confusing. It is most often referred to as "Ruby", which is even
   more annoying and confusing than having no name, because it
   leads to endless confusion between the features of the Ruby
   Programming Language and a particular Ruby Implementation.

It is also sometimes called "MRI" (for "Matz's Ruby
Implementation"), CRuby or MatzRuby.

[MRI implements Ruby Threads as Green Threads within its
interpreter](http://RedMine.Ruby-Lang.Org/repositories/annotate/ruby-18/ext/thread/thread.c). Unfortunately, it doesn't allow those threads
to be scheduled in parallel, they can only run one thread at a
time.

However, any number of C Threads (POSIX Threads etc.) can run
in parallel to the Ruby Thread, so external C Libraries, or MRI
C Extensions that create threads of their own can still run in
parallel.

2. The second implementation is [YARV](http://WWW.AtDot.Net/yarv/) (short for "Yet
   Another Ruby VM"). [YARV implements Ruby Threads as POSIX or
   Windows NT Threads](http://RedMine.Ruby-Lang.Org/repositories/annotate/ruby-19/thread.c), however, it uses a Global Interpreter
   Lock (GIL) to ensure that only one Ruby Thread can actually be
   scheduled at any one time.

Like MRI, C Threads *can* actually run parallel to Ruby Threads.

In the future, it is possible, that the GIL *might* get broken
down into more fine-grained locks, thus allowing more and more
code to actually run in parallel, but that's so far away, it is
not even *planned* yet.

3. [JRuby](https://www.jruby.org/) [implements Ruby Threads as Native Threads](http://www.restlessprogrammer.com/2013/02/multi-threading-in-jruby.html),
   where "Native Threads" in case of the JVM obviously means "JVM
   Threads". JRuby imposes no additional locking on them. So,
   whether those threads can actually run in parallel depends on
   the JVM: some JVMs implement JVM Threads as OS Threads and some
   as Green Threads. (The mainstream JVMs from Sun/Oracle use exclusively OS threads since JDK 1.3)
4. [XRuby](http://XRuby.GoogleCode.Com/) also [implements Ruby Threads as JVM Threads](http://Code.Google.Com/p/xruby/source/browse/trunk/src/com/xruby/runtime/builtin/RubyThread.java#21). **Update**: XRuby is dead.
5. [IronRuby](http://IronRuby.Net/) [implements Ruby Threads as Native Threads](http://IronRuby.RubyForge.Org/svn/trunk/src/IronRuby.Libraries/Builtins/ThreadOps.cs),
   where "Native Threads" in case of the CLR obviously means
   "CLR Threads". IronRuby imposes no additional locking on them,
   so, they should run in parallel, as long as your CLR supports
   that.
6. [Ruby.NET](http://RubyDotNetCompiler.GoogleCode.Com/) also [implements Ruby Threads as CLR
   Threads](http://Code.Google.Com/p/rubydotnetcompiler/source/browse/trunk/src/RubyRuntime/Built-in%20Classes/Thread.cs#21). **Update:** Ruby.NET is dead.
7. [Rubinius](http://Rubini.us/) [implements Ruby Threads as Green Threads
   within its Virtual Machine](https://GitHub.Com/EvanPhx/Rubinius/tree/master/kernel/core/thread.rb#L9). More precisely: the Rubinius
   VM exports a very lightweight, very flexible
   concurrency/parallelism/non-local control-flow construct, called
   a "[Task](https://GitHub.Com/EvanPhx/Rubinius/tree/cpp/vm/builtin/task.cpp)", and all other concurrency constructs (Threads in
   this discussion, but also [Continuations](https://GitHub.Com/EvanPhx/Rubinius/tree/master/kernel/core/continuation.rb#L45), [Actors](https://GitHub.Com/EvanPhx/Rubinius/tree/master/lib/actor.rb#L31) and
   other stuff) are implemented in pure Ruby, using Tasks.

Rubinius can not (currently) schedule Threads in parallel,
however, adding that isn't too much of a problem: Rubinius can
already [run several VM instances in several POSIX Threads in
parallel](https://GitHub.Com/EvanPhx/Rubinius/tree/master/kernel/core/vm.rb#L5), within one Rubinius process. Since Threads are
actually implemented in Ruby, they can, like any other Ruby
object, be serialized and sent to a different VM in a different
POSIX Thread. (That's the same model the BEAM [Erlang](http://Erlang.Org/) VM
uses for SMP concurrency. It is already [implemented for
Rubinius Actors](https://GitHub.Com/EvanPhx/Rubinius/tree/master/lib/vmactor.rb).)

**Update**: The information about Rubinius in this answer is about the Shotgun VM, which doesn't exist anymore. The "new" C++ VM does not use green threads scheduled across multiple VMs (i.e. Erlang/BEAM style), it uses a more traditional single VM with multiple native OS threads model, just like the one employed by, say, the CLR, Mono, and pretty much every JVM.

8. [MacRuby](http://MacRuby.Org/) started out as a port of YARV on top of the
   Objective-C Runtime and CoreFoundation and Cocoa Frameworks. It
   has now significantly diverged from YARV, but AFAIK it currently
   still [shares the same Threading Model with YARV](http://MacRuby.Org/trac/browser/MacRuby/trunk/thread.c?annotate=blame).
   **Update:** MacRuby depends on apples garbage collector which is declared deprecated and will be removed in later versions of MacOSX, MacRuby is undead.
9. [Cardinal](https://github.com/parrot/cardinal) is a Ruby Implementation for the [Parrot
   Virtual Machine](http://ParrotCode.Org/). It doesn't implement threads yet, however,
   when it does, it will probably implement them as [Parrot
   Threads](http://SVN.Perl.Org/viewvc/parrot/trunk/src/thread.c?view=annotate). **Update**: Cardinal seems very inactive/dead.
10. [MagLev](http://MagLev.GemStone.Com/) is a Ruby Implementation for the [GemStone/S
    Smalltalk VM](http://GemStone.Com/products/smalltalk/). I have no information what threading model
    GemStone/S uses, what threading model MagLev uses or even if
    threads are even implemented yet (probably not).
11. [HotRuby](http://HotRuby.Yukoba.Jp/) is *not* a full Ruby Implementation of its
    own. It is an implementation of a YARV bytecode VM in
    JavaScript. HotRuby doesn't support threads (yet?) and when it
    does, they won't be able to run in parallel, because JavaScript
    has no support for true parallelism. There is an ActionScript
    version of HotRuby, however, and ActionScript might actually
    support parallelism. **Update**: HotRuby is dead.

Unfortunately, only two of these 11 Ruby Implementations are
actually production-ready: MRI and JRuby.

So, if you want true parallel threads, JRuby is currently your
only choice – not that that's a bad one: JRuby is actually faster
than MRI, and arguably more stable.

Otherwise, the "classical" Ruby solution is to use processes
instead of threads for parallelism. The Ruby Core Library
contains the [`Process` module](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core/classes/Process.html) with the [`Process.fork`
method](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core/classes/Process.html#M003179) which makes it dead easy to fork off another Ruby
process. Also, the Ruby Standard Library contains the
[Distributed Ruby (dRuby / dRb)](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/stdlib/libdoc/drb/rdoc/) library, which allows Ruby
code to be trivially distributed across multiple processes, not
only on the same machine but also across the network.

Comment: but using fork will break usage on jruby... just saying

Comment: This is a great answer. However it is subject to a lot of link rot. I don't know where these resources may have moved though.

Comment: This one is the best one I came across, I was just wondering if Ruby support multi threading like java, had checked a few other blogs and all apparently seem to have knowledge on the specific implementation. I was confused which blog to follow ;)

Thankyou very much @Jörg for such a comprehensive explanation.

Answer (score 23):

Ruby 1.8 only has green threads, there is no way to create a real "OS-level" thread.  But, ruby 1.9 will have a new feature called fibers, which will allow you to create actual OS-level threads.  Unfortunately, Ruby 1.9 is still in beta, it is scheduled to be stable in a couple of months.

Another alternative is to use JRuby.  JRuby implements threads as OS-level theads, there are no "green threads" in it.  The latest version of JRuby is 1.1.4 and is equivalent to Ruby 1.8

Comment: It's false that Ruby 1.8 has only green threads, several implementations of Ruby 1.8 have native threads: JRuby, XRuby, Ruby.NET and IronRuby.

Fibers don't allow the creation of native threads, they are *more lightweight* than threads. They are actually semi-coroutines, i.e. they are cooperative.

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious from Josh's answer that he means Ruby 1.8 the runtime, a.k.a. MRI, and not Ruby 1.8 the language, when he says Ruby 1.8.

Comment: @Theo It's also obvious that he messes up concepts in his answer. Fibers are not a way to create native threads, as already mentioned, they are even more lightweight things than threads and current cruby has native threads but with GIL.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the implementation:

- MRI doesn't have, YARV is closer.
- JRuby and MacRuby have.

Ruby has [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) as `Blocks`, `lambdas` and `Procs`. To take full advantage of closures and multiple cores in JRuby, [Java's executors](http://blog.bitmelt.com/2013/05/concurrent-tasks-in-jruby.html) come in handy; for MacRuby I like [GCD's queues](http://seanlilmateus.github.io/blog/2012/05/31/getting-started-with-grand-central-dispatch-in-macruby-and-rubymotion/).

Note that, being able to create *real "OS-level" threads* doesn't imply that you can use multiple cpu cores for parallel processing. Look at the examples below.

This is the output of [a simple Ruby program which uses 3 threads](https://gist.github.com/user454322/8785580) using Ruby 2.1.0:

```
(jalcazar@mac ~)$ ps -M 69877
USER     PID   TT   %CPU STAT PRI     STIME     UTIME COMMAND
jalcazar 69877 s002    0.0 S    31T   0:00.01   0:00.04 /Users/jalcazar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby threads.rb
   69877         0.0 S    31T   0:00.01   0:00.00 
   69877        33.4 S    31T   0:00.01   0:08.73 
   69877        43.1 S    31T   0:00.01   0:08.73 
   69877        22.8 R    31T   0:00.01   0:08.65
```

As you can see here, there are four OS threads, however only the one with state `R` is running. This is due to a limitation in how Ruby's threads are implemented.

---

Same program, now with JRuby. You can see three threads with state `R`, which means they are running in parallel.

```
(jalcazar@mac ~)$ ps -M 72286
USER     PID   TT   %CPU STAT PRI     STIME     UTIME COMMAND
jalcazar 72286 s002    0.0 S    31T   0:00.01   0:00.01 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Djdk.home= -Djruby.home=/Users/jalcazar/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.10 -Djruby.script=jruby -Djruby.shell=/bin/sh -Djffi.boot.library.path=/Users/jalcazar/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.10/lib/jni:/Users/jalcazar/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.10/lib/jni/Darwin -Xss2048k -Dsun.java.command=org.jruby.Main -cp  -Xbootclasspath/a:/Users/jalcazar/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.10/lib/jruby.jar -Xmx1924M -XX:PermSize=992m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org/jruby/Main threads.rb
   72286         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
   72286         0.0 S    33T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
   72286         0.0 S    31T   0:00.09   0:02.34 
   72286         7.9 S    31T   0:00.15   0:04.63 
   72286         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
   72286         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
   72286         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
   72286         0.0 S    31T   0:00.04   0:01.68 
   72286         0.0 S    31T   0:00.03   0:01.54 
   72286         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
   72286         0.0 S    31T   0:00.01   0:00.01 
   72286         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.01 
   72286         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.03 
   72286        74.2 R    31T   0:09.21   0:37.73 
   72286        72.4 R    31T   0:09.24   0:37.71 
   72286        74.7 R    31T   0:09.24   0:37.80
```

---

The same program, now with MacRuby. There are also three threads running in parallel. This is because [MacRuby threads are POSIX threads](https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby/wiki/Why-MacRuby%3F#2-thread-support) (*real "OS-level" threads*) and there is [no GVL](http://vimeo.com/67731482#t=19m47s)

```
(jalcazar@mac ~)$ ps -M 38293
USER     PID   TT   %CPU STAT PRI     STIME     UTIME COMMAND
jalcazar 38293 s002    0.0 R     0T   0:00.02   0:00.10 /Users/jalcazar/.rvm/rubies/macruby-0.12/usr/bin/macruby threads.rb
   38293         0.0 S    33T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
   38293       100.0 R    31T   0:00.04   0:21.92 
   38293       100.0 R    31T   0:00.04   0:21.95 
   38293       100.0 R    31T   0:00.04   0:21.99
```

---

Once again, the same program but now with the good old MRI. Due to the fact that this implementation uses green-threads, only one thread shows up

```
(jalcazar@mac ~)$ ps -M 70032
USER     PID   TT   %CPU STAT PRI     STIME     UTIME COMMAND
jalcazar 70032 s002  100.0 R    31T   0:00.08   0:26.62 /Users/jalcazar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby threads.rb
```

If you are interested in Ruby multi-threading you might find my report *[Debugging parallel programs using fork handlers](https://modprobe.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/jalcazar_pmam20151.pdf)* interesting.
For a more general overview of the Ruby internals *[Ruby Under a Microscope](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781593275273.do)* is a good read. 
Also, [Ruby Threads and the Global Interpreter Lock in C](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/2.2.0.preview1/files/thread_pthread.h#annotation=4057266&line=38) in Omniref explains in the source code why Ruby threads don't run in parallel.

Comment: By RMI, you mean MRI?

Answer (score 4):

How about using [drb](http://chadfowler.com/ruby/drb.html)? It's not real multi-threading but communication between several processes, but you can use it now in 1.8 and it's fairly low friction.

Answer (score 3):

I'll let the "System Monitor" answer this question.  I'm executing the same code (below, which calculates prime numbers) with 8 Ruby threads running on an i7 (4 hyperthreaded-core) machine in both cases... the first run is with:

jruby 1.5.6 (ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 249) (2014-02-03 6586)
(OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_75) [amd64-java]

The second is with:

ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Interestingly, the CPU is higher for JRuby threads, but the time to completion is slightly shorter for the interpreted Ruby.  It's kind of difficult to tell from the graph, but the second (interpreted Ruby) run uses about 1/2 the CPUs (no hyperthreading?)

[image]

```
def eratosthenes(n)
  nums = [nil, nil, *2..n]
  (2..Math.sqrt(n)).each do |i|
    (i**2..n).step(i){|m| nums[m] = nil}  if nums[i]
  end
  nums.compact
end

MAX_PRIME=10000000
THREADS=8
threads = []

1.upto(THREADS) do |num|
  puts "Starting thread #{num}"
  threads[num]=Thread.new { eratosthenes MAX_PRIME }
end

1.upto(THREADS) do |num|
    threads[num].join
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MRI, then you can write the threaded code in C either as an extension or using the ruby-inline gem.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need parallelism in Ruby for a Production level system (where you cannot employ a beta) processes are probably a better alternative. 
But, it is most definitely worth trying threads under JRuby first.

Also if you are interested in future of threading under Ruby, you might find this [article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/05/ruby-threading-futures) useful.

Comment: JRuby is a good option. For parallel processing using processes I like  https://github.com/grosser/parallel `Parallel.map(['a','b','c'], :in_processes=>3){...`

Answer (score 1):

Here is some info on Rinda which is Ruby implementation of Linda (parallel processing and distributed computing paradigm) http://charmalloc.blogspot.com/2009/12/linda-tuples-rinda-drb-parallel.html

Answer (score 1):

Because could not edit that answer, so add a new reply here.

**Update(2017-05-08)**

This article is very old, and information is not follow current
(2017) tread, Following is some supplement:

12. [Opal](https://github.com/opal/opal) is a Ruby to JavaScript source-to-source compiler. It also has an implementation of the Ruby corelib, It current very active develompent, and exist a great deal of (frontend) framework worked on it.
    and production ready. Because base on javascript, it not support parallel threads.
13. [truffleruby](https://github.com/graalvm/truffleruby) is a high performance implementation of the Ruby programming language. Built on the GraalVM by Oracle Labs,TruffleRuby is a fork of JRuby, combining it with code from the Rubinius project, and also containing code from the standard implementation of Ruby, MRI, still live development, not production ready.
    This version ruby seem like born for performance, I don't know if support parallel threads, but I think it should.