# Ruby multithreading / multiprocessing readings

Tags: ruby, multithreading, multiprocessing

Can anyone recommend any good multithreading / processing books / sites which go into detail about the intricacies of Ruby multithreading / multiprocessing?

I tried using ruby threading and basically in deadlock-free code on 1.9vm it ran into deadlocks in jruby. Yes I realize the differences are drastic (jruby has no GIL) but I wanted to know if there are strategies or set of classes for multithreaded programming in ruby that I just need to read up on.

Side note: was kinda weird going from java to ruby having to define if i want a re-enterent lock vs not.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999482/what-practical-effect-will-different-ruby-threading-models-ruby-vs-jruby-have-o/2372518#2372518

Comment: http://www.igvita.com/2008/11/13/concurrency-is-a-myth-in-ruby is good, but wouldn't explain why jruby is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Ruby 1.9 you can try Fiber it's a big improvement in threading in Ruby

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Fiber.html

http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/08/ruby-1-9-fibers

Comment: I wouldn't call it an improvement, just a different feature used to accomplish similar tasks. A big improvement is threading in JRuby's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, the dRuby book has a chapter about DRb multithreading, and it touches some basic aspects of Ruby Multithreading. It was written by the same man who wrote dRuby/ERB, and looks pretty good.

Comment: What is dRuby? I have not heard of it.