# How do I manage ruby threads so they finish all their work?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, threadpool

I have a computation that can be divided into independent units and the way I'm dealing with it now is by creating a fixed number of threads and then handing off chunks of work to be done in each thread. So in pseudo code here's what it looks like

```
# main thread
work_units.take(10).each {|work_unit| spawn_thread_for work_unit}

def spawn_thread_for(work)
  Thread.new do
    do_some work
    more_work = work_units.pop
    spawn_thread_for more_work unless more_work.nil?
  end
end
```

Basically once the initial number of threads is created each one does some work and then keeps taking stuff to be done from the work stack until nothing is left. Everything works fine when I run things in irb but when I execute the script using the interpreter things don't work out so well. I'm not sure how to make the main thread wait until all the work is finished. Is there a nice way of doing this or am I stuck with executing `sleep 10 until work_units.empty?` in the main thread

Comment: Doesn't `take(10)` mean that only the first 10 `work_units` will be processed, ever?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: Actually no, but rereading the question it looks like `work_units` would be out of scope for `spawn_thread_for` for the line `more_work = work_units.pop`

Comment: In the actual code it's an instance variable so there are no scoping issues.

Comment: NOTE: [depending on which ruby implementation you use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087/does-ruby-have-real-multithreading), the Threads might not really work in parallel (e.g. use multiple CPU cores / get the work done faster by splitting over multiple threads).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you modify `spawn_thread_for` to save a reference to your created `Thread`, then you can call `Thread#join` on the thread to wait for completion:

```
x = Thread.new { sleep 0.1; print "x"; print "y"; print "z" }
a = Thread.new { print "a"; print "b"; sleep 0.2; print "c" }
x.join # Let the threads finish before
a.join # main thread exits...
```

produces:

```
abxyzc
```

(Stolen from the `ri Thread.new` documentation. See the `ri Thread.join` documentation for some more details.)

So, if you amend `spawn_thread_for` to save the Thread references, you can join on them all:

(Untested, but ought to give the flavor)

```
# main thread
work_units = Queue.new # and fill the queue...

threads = []
10.downto(1) do
  threads << Thread.new do
    loop do
      w = work_units.pop
      Thread::exit() if w.nil?
      do_some_work(w)
    end
  end
end

# main thread continues while work threads devour work

threads.each(&:join)
```

Comment: But this can potentially make `threads` quite large because when a thread completes it's reference is still in the `threads` array. Moreover `threads` is being modified while `threads.each(&:join)` is executing so this still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @davidk, perhaps instead of calling `spawn_thread_for` within each thread, simply look for more work and start directly?

Comment: @sarnold, I only want a fixed number of threads to be active. If I look for more work and then start a thread it's possible I can overshoot the limit of 10 threads because of the uncertainty in how scheduling happens and the amount of work each thread is doing.

Comment: @davidk01, _why start another thread_ when one is 'done'? Just grab a new work unit in the already-running thread. Start ten threads and then let them start sucking work units off your work queue. (See the `Queue` class for a thread-safe queue implementation.)

Comment: @sarnold, great point. I didn't think of it so thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @davidk01, I re-wrote the answer a bit to try to show what I mean, maybe it'll even be useful. :)

Answer (score 37):

In ruby 1.9 (and 2.0), you can use `ThreadsWait` from the stdlib for this purpose:

```
require 'thread'
require 'thwait'

threads = []
threads << Thread.new { }
threads << Thread.new { }
ThreadsWait.all_waits(*threads)
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference between `ThreadsWait.all_waits(*threads)` and `threads.each { |thr| thr.join }`?

Comment: The second way is the modern API.

Answer (score 3):

```
Thread.list.each{ |t| t.join unless t == Thread.current }
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are replicating what the Parallel Each ([Peach](https://github.com/schleyfox/peach)) library provides.

Comment: I don't need an entire library for the simple use case I have in mind but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Thread#join](https://apidock.com/ruby/Thread/join)

**join(p1 = v1) public**

> The calling thread will suspend execution and run thr. Does not return until thr exits or until limit seconds have passed. If the time limit expires, nil will be returned, otherwise thr is returned.

Also you can use [Enumerable#each_slice](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice) to iterate over the work units in batches

```
work_units.each_slice(10) do |batch|
  # handle each work unit in a thread
  threads = batch.map do |work_unit|
    spawn_thread_for work_unit
  end

  # wait until current batch work units finish before handling the next batch
  threads.each(&:join)
end
```