# Ruby Parallel/Multithread Programming to read huge database

Tags: ruby, multithreading, multicore

I have a ruby script reading a huge table (~20m rows), doing some processing and feeding it over to Solr for indexing purposes. This has been a big bottleneck in our process. I am planning to speed things in here and I'd like to achieve some kind of parallelism. I am confused about Ruby's multithreading nature. Our servers have 
`ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [x86_64-linux]`. From [this blog post](http://www.igvita.com/2008/11/13/concurrency-is-a-myth-in-ruby/) and [this question at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087/does-ruby-have-real-multithreading) it is visible that Ruby does not have a "real" multi threading approach. Our servers have multiple cores, so using [parallel gem](https://github.com/grosser/parallel) seems another approach to me.

What approach should I go with? Also, any inputs on parallel-database-read-feeding systems would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you access the database? Can you show us some code?

Comment: I use mysql gem to fetch N (~500) records at a time using MySQL's limit, offset parameters. Batch process them and batch feed them to Solr. Is more info needed?

Answer (score 4):

You can parallelize this at the OS level. Change the script so that it can take a range of lines from your input file

```
$ reader_script --lines=10000:20000 mytable.txt
```

Then execute multiple instances of the script.

```
$ reader_script --lines=0:10000 mytable.txt&
$ reader_script --lines=10000:20000 mytable.txt&
$ reader_script --lines=20000:30000 mytable.txt&
```

Unix will distribute them to different cores automatically.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable approach. We have 8 cores, so I can run upto 8 instances very easily.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance of upgrading to Ruby 1.9? It's usually faster than 1.8.7.

It's true that Ruby suffers from having a [GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) but if multithreading would solve your problem then you can take a look at [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) since it supports true threading.

Also you better make sure it's the CPU that's the bottleneck because if it's I/O multithreading might not buy you much.