# How to make an async POST request in Ruby using RestClient

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, rest-client

Can we make an asynchronous POST request to a resource in Ruby using the RestClient library ( https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client )?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "asyncronous POST request" you mean "fire-and-forget" kind of request, then you can execute it on another thread.

```
Thread.new do
  # do your request here
end
```

Note, however, that not all Ruby implementations use real concurrent threads. See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087/does-ruby-have-real-multithreading) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Using ['send_later'](https://github.com/defunkt/resque#section_Jobs_send_later_async) of Resque should be a better option.