# Ruby 1.9.X combination in multicore?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, ruby-1.9.3

I'm doing analysis on combination blocks. Is it possible to have this run on multicore?

```
x = (1...30).to_a.combination(10).collect { |x| x }
puts x
```

Comment: Have you looked at any of the other Stack Overflow questions on multithreading?

Comment: Didn't see much: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ruby+multi+threading There's also a difference, cannot use JRuby, and the threading I know how to use, do not push to different cores.

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087/does-ruby-have-real-multithreading ? If not, then use [tag:ruby+multi-threading] and sort by votes.

Comment: thx but thats for ruby 1.8... a comment suggests "fibers" in ruby 1.9 make it possible without expansion