# Would threading be beneficial for this situation?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mongodb

I have a CSV file with over 1 million rows. I also have a database that contains such data in a formatted way.

I want to check and verify the data in the CSV file and the data in the database.

Is it beneficial/reduces time to thread reading from the CSV file and use a connection pool to the database?

How well does Ruby handle threading?

I am using MongoDB, also.

Comment: If MongoDB provides a load utility it more efficient to use that than roll your own.  (and much faster, usually.

Comment: And also, if you using MRI ruby implementation (that is "usual C-ruby"), note that you can't use native threads, as it is finely described in "[Does ruby have real multithreading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087/does-ruby-have-real-multithreading)" and will probably need to spawn processes for that task. I would also vote for smth external to Ruby in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say without knowing some more details about the specifics of what you want the app to feel like when someone initiates this comparison. So, to answer, some general advice that should apply fairly well regardless of the problem you might want to thread.

#### Threading does NOT make something computationally less costly

Threading doesn't make things less costly in terms of computation time. It just lets two things happen in parallel. So, beware that you're not falling into the common misconception that, "Threading makes my app faster because the user doesn't wait for things." - this isn't true, and threading actually adds quite a bit of complexity.

So, if you kick off this DB vs. CSV comparison task, threading isn't going to make that comparison take any less time. What it might do is allow you to tell the user, "Ok, I'm going to check that for you," right away, while doing the comparison in a separate thread of execution. You still have to figure out how to get back to the user when the comparison is done.

#### Think about WHY you want to thread, rather than simply approaching it as whether threading is a good solution for long tasks

Like I said above, threading doesn't make things faster. At best, it uses computing resources in a way that is either more efficient, or gives a better user experience, or both.

If the user of the app (maybe it's just you) doesn't mind waiting for the comparison to run, then don't add threading because you're just going to add complexity and it won't be any faster. If this comparison takes a long time and you'd rather "do it in the background" then threading **might** be an answer for you. Just be aware that if you do this you're then adding another concern, which is, how do you update the user when the background job is done?

#### Threading involves extra overhead and app complexity, which you will then have to manage within your app - tread lightly

There are other concerns as well, such as, how do I schedule that worker thread to make sure it doesn't hog the computing resources? Are the setting of thread priorities an option in my environment, and if so, how will adjusting them affect the use of computing resources?

Threading and the extra overhead involved will almost definitely make your comparison take LONGER (in terms of absolute time it takes to do the comparison). The real advantage is if you don't care about completion time (the time between when the comparison starts and when it is done) but instead the responsiveness of the app to the user, and/or the total throughput that can be achieved (e.g. the number of simultaneous comparisons you can be running, and as a result the total number of comparisons you can complete within a given time span).

#### Threading doesn't guarantee that your available CPU cores are used efficiently

See [Green Threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) vs. native threads - some languages (depending on their threading implementation) can schedule threads across CPUs.

Threading doesn't necessarily mean your threads wind up getting run in multiple physical CPU cores - in fact in many cases they definitely **won't**. If all your app's threads run on the same physical core, then they aren't truly running in parallel - they are just splitting CPU time in a way that may make them look like they are running in parallel.

For these reasons, depending on the structure of your app, it's often less complicated to send background tasks to a separate worker **process** (process, not thread), which can easily be scheduled onto available CPU cores at the OS level. Separate processes (as opposed to separate threads) also remove a lot of the scheduling concerns within your app, because you essentially offload the decision about how to schedule things onto the OS itself.

**This last point is pretty important.** OS schedulers are extremely likely to be smarter and more efficiently designed than whatever algorithm you might come up with in your app.