# How can I efficiently poll a lot of servers?

Tags: ruby, polling, minecraft

I am looking for a good way to poll a lot of servers for their status through TCP. I am currently using synchronous code and the Minecraft Query Protocol, but whenever a server is offline the rest of the queue gets hold up.

Another problem I am experiencing with my current code is that some servers tend to block my server I use for polling in their firewall, and thus their servers appear offline on my serverlist.

I am using a Ruby rake task with an infinite loop in which every Minecraft server in my MongoDB database gets checked and updated every +- 10 minutes (I try to set this interval by letting the loop sleep `(600/ s.count.to_i).ceil` seconds.

Is there any way I can do this task efficiently (and prevent servers from blacklisting my IP in their firewall), preferably with Async code in Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use non-blocking sockets to check - multithreading. The best thing to do is spawn several threads at once to check several servers at once - that way your main thread won't get held up.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087/does-ruby-have-real-multithreading) contains a lot of information about multithreading in Ruby - you should be able to spawn multiple concurrent threads at once, or at least use non-blocking sockets.

Another point given by @Lie Ryan, you can use [IO.Select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-select) to poll a array of servers, all at once. It will return an array of "online" servers when it's done - this could be more elegant than spawning multiple threads.

Comment: rather than multithreading, it's usually  better to use IO.select.

Comment: I like the IO.Select method. Should I just execute the IO.Select line of code every let's say 10 minutes then?

Comment: You can do this, make sure the previous check has already ended though

Comment: I'll look into using IO.select, thanks. I'll accept this answer for now

Comment: [em-synchrony](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony) makes it a lot easier to write non-blocking asynchronous code using fibers. It's worth checking out rather than doing it with nested callbacks.