# Implementing multithreading in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading

I have written a Rails application which have a db of set of students and that db gets updated on daily basis with the help of a rake task. I mean this task updates entry corresponding to each student id, i.e. first student id 1 then for student id 2 and so on like following.:

```
task :update_db => :environment do
   student_ids = Student.map{|x|x.id}
   student_ids.each do |sid|
    begin
      StudentHelper.update_db_entry(sid)
    rescue Exception => e
      Rails.logger.info "#{e.message}"
      Rails.logger.info "#{e.backtrace.inspect}"
    end
   end
end
```

Here entry of a student in the db is independent of other students so it appears that we can update the entry of more than one student at the same time. I think this is only possible with mutithreading.

I am not getting any clue how to proceed, I have no idea how to implement multithreading in ruby on rails application.

Comment: Multithreading is probably not necessary here unless you are having a serious issue with performance. Also a large number of threads are going to tie up your database, which means other applications using the database will be less responsive

Answer (score 0):

To spawn a new thread and make it do some work using AR models, use the following code:

```
thread = Thread.new do 
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
    #your code updating students here
  end
end
```

You'll need to split the id numbers into equal parts and assign a part to each thread. Since each thread will require a database connection from the pool, you can quickly exhaust the available connections so don't use too many. The number of db connections in the pool are set in `config/database.yml`.

You can use the `join` method of the thread object to wait until that thread is finished, in case you want to perform further actions once all records are processed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "classic" Ruby then threads are not actually executed in parellel, they running in one ruby process in OS. For a real parallelism you should use [processes](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Process.html)

see more here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087/does-ruby-have-real-multithreading)