# Rails: How to execute one task per user in parallel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, task

I have one simple rake task that execute some action per user. Something like these:

```
task users_actions: :environment do ||
    User.all.each { |u|
        # Some actions here
    }
end
```

The problem it's that it doesn't start with the next user until it finished one. What I want is to execute these in parallel. How can I do that? It's even posible?

Thanks,

Comment: Very good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087/does-ruby-have-real-multithreading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there was a good library available, it would be better to use it rather than implementing everything from scratch. `concurrent-ruby` has all kinds of utility classes for writing concurrent code, but I'm not sure if they have something suitable for this use case; anyways, I'll show you how to do it from scratch.

First pull in the `thread` library:

```
require 'thread'
```

Make a thread-safe queue, and stick all the users on it:

```
queue = Queue.new
User.all.each { |user| queue << user }
```

Start some number of worker threads, and make them process items from the queue until all are done.

```
threads = 5.times.collect do
  Thread.new do
    while true
      user = queue.pop(true) rescue break
      # do something with the user
      # this had better be thread-safe, or you will live to regret it!
    end
  end
end
```

Then wait until all the threads finish:

```
threads.each(&:join)
```

Again, please make sure that the code which processes each user is thread-safe! The power of multi-threading is in your hands, don't abuse it!

**NOTE:** If your user-processing code is very CPU-intensive, you might consider running this on Rubinius or JRuby, so that more than one thread can run Ruby code at the same time.

Comment: While this answer would probably speed up processing using concurrency, it does not provide true parallelism.

Comment: @Jeremiah, that depends. If you run under JRuby or RBX, it definitely does.

Comment: You're absolutely correct sir, I was assuming MRI. Edit?

Comment: These usually ends on a "Circular dependency detected while autoloading Setting." (Setting is one module name) How can I fix these?

Comment: @Victor, that has nothing to do with this. That error means that you have a file somewhere which uses `Setting`, but `setting.rb` loads or requires the very same file.