# Can Ruby on Rails app run into multi-core?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiprocessing

Would it make a difference versus the single core into terms of performance in Ruby on rails  app
and if i have multi-core how i manage rails through  multi-core 
if multi-core processor same idea of distributed servers

Comment: I am not sure, if I get your question right. Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087/does-ruby-have-real-multithreading helps?

Comment: It's very simple: more cores/processors - more parallel workers. If you have only one worker, you don't need more than one core.

Comment: also depends on if the ror application is built for multi processes/threads. Ruby implementations can have the capability in its architecture but the app may still lack it

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you specify that your rails app run "8 processes" at once and each will use one core.  The way I do it is by using phusion passenger [in my case, with nginx] and you may get it to work like

passenger_max_pool_size 8

passenger_max_instances_per_app 8

If you want to make sure your cores are all busy [and have enough RAM] then possibly set them to size 16'ish

Answer (score -1):

Multicore servers only boost performance if the rails app is running in multithreaded mode of in multiprocess mode. Ruby currently supports 'green' threads, which are lightweight and not true processor threads. Rails has support for multithreading, but gem support could be lacking and would probably be unstable for production. To make the best use of a multicore server, running a web server like unicorn or passenger, which can spawn rails processes per core, would provide you the best performance boost

Comment: Ruby has real threads since 1.9. Which is 4 years old by now (1.9.3). 1.9.0 is 8 years old. Green threads were a thing only up to and including 1.8.