# Making parallel calls with twitter gem

Tags: ruby, twitter, concurrency, mri

I am using [twitter](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) gem to make API calls from my app and fetch some data.

I have an array of `user_ids` and I want to fetch all tweets of each user by doing something like this:

```
user_ids.map {|user_id| Client.user_timeline(user_id)}
```

Is there any way to make these calls concurrent? Is there any way that I can use [typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) or any similar gem with [twitter](https://github.com/sferik/twitter)? Is there any other way I can make this operation fast?

Comment: Consider making your api calls in [separate threads](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Thread.html).

Comment: @Uzbekjon I thought of using threads at first, but I came across this [question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087/does-ruby-have-real-multithreading). As I am using CRuby, I don't think threading would help me here. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Nope, that would work just fine. The SO question you linked to discussed "true OS-level multithreading". But, you don't care how multi-threading is implemented, right. As far as it does the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your API calls in [Ruby threads](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Thread.html) to run them concurrently:

```
tweets, threads = [], []

threads = user_ids.map do |user_id|
  Thread.new { tweets << Client.user_timeline(user_id) }
end

threads.each(&:join)

# All the tweets are in the `tweets` array
puts tweets
```

Comment: Hi @Uzbekjon - this is not the correct forum, but I just want to let you know that your course on Udemy - Ruby Metaprogramming - is the best I've ever taken!  This is the only way I could find to contact you and let you know! ;)

Comment: Hi @fatfrog. Thank you. I am glad you liked it. It means a lot. PS. I am pretty much `uzbekjon` everywhere in case you need to contact me in the future ;)